# UTC timestamp not returning correct time

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I get a date string from the server in `EST` so I convert it

example date `2013-04-16T11:56:07.15`

```
incidentDate = l.item(0).getTextContent();                                  
DateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",Locale.US);
dformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York"));
Date timestamp;

try
{                                   
    timestamp = dformat.parse(incidentDate);
    incidentDateLong = timestamp.getTime();

}
catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

the timestamp that gets returned is `1366113367015`

If I plug that into a converter on this website to check the date

http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/

the milliseconds does not seem to be the correct date, it gives me `Tue Apr 16 2013 07:56:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` which is not was was sent to me from the server.

When I go to convert the date back it pulls the date back even further away from the actual date

```
Date incDate = new Date(dateInMili);

DateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a",Locale.US);

String dateStr = dformat.format(incDate);
```

Is something wrong with my formatter? I dont understand the problem

Comment: You should check [this question and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15994657/1122039).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York")
```

That's not a valid time zone ID. You want:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
```

Note the underscore. Personally I think it's a shame that `getTimeZone` gives no indication that it hasn't actually found the time zone you've asked for, but it's been that way for a long time :(

Comment: wow I just spend 4 hours trying to figure this out and all it was, was a stupid underscore....what a waste of time.

thanks though!!