# LocalDateTime and JodaDate conflicts

Tags: jpa, jodatime, activiti, auditing, localdate

I'm creating a multi module Maven project using spring MVC, hibernate, Spring Data JPA project.
Currently I have integrated an Activiti workflow engine and using Joda date dependency. But my model class use java 8 LocalDateTime.
Spring Data JPA Auditing (@CreatedDate, @LastModifiedDate, ...) also enabled and configured in separate maven module(common-service)

**project structure -**

[image]

**model class -**

[image]

**JPA Config file -**

[image]

---

My question is when i save the workflow object the **Joda LocalDate** not present error occurs

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.joda.time.LocalDate not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:108)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:913)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:472)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:437)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getRequiredTypeInfo(GenericConversionService.java:292)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:86)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.DefaultAuditableBeanWrapperFactory$DateConvertingAuditableBeanWrapper.<init>(DefaultAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory$MappingMetadataAuditableBeanWrapper.<init>(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.lambda$null$1(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:84)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.lambda$getBeanWrapperFor$3(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:78)
    at java.util.Optional.flatMap(Optional.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.getBeanWrapperFor(MappingAuditableBeanWrapperFactory.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.touch(AuditingHandler.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.markCreated(AuditingHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForCreate(AuditingEntityListener.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.preCreate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.save(Unknown Source)
    at my.com.scicom.esd.workflowservice.service.WorkFlowService.createWorkFlow(WorkFlowService.java:87)
    at my.com.scicom.esd.workflowservice.controller.WorkFlowController.createWorkflow(WorkFlowController.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.LocalDate
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
        ... 109 more
```

and there are no other date field rather than created date and modified date with JPA Auditing

Answer (score 1):

Well, somewhere in that huge stack-trace is a piece of code looking for the `org.joda.time.LocalDate` class "by name" and the JVM can't find it.

The only way to locate the issue is by debugging - I would start at the `GenericConversionService.getRequiredTypeInfo()` and search up the stack.

### But, regarding the model class you listed...

Both the `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` are using the (I assume Java 8's) `LocalDateTime` which might be supported by [Spring Data Auditing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/#auditing), but since `LocalDateTime` is lacking the *uniqueness* information (i.e. the time zone) there might be some (Spring Framework) code attempting to convert `LocalDateTime` to JodaTime.

One should use a value that is unique all over the world for auditing.

An example using your model and [the logic I provided on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994450/joda-datetime-to-timestamp-conversion/15994657#15994657)...
If a user in India (**India Standard Time, GMT+5:30**) creates a `Workflow` instance at 9 o'clock in the morning, and another user in the UK (**London, GMT+0**) also creates a `Workflow` instance at 9 o'clock in the morning, those two instantiations would be 5 and a half hours apart but listed e.g. to a third user by the application as created at the same time which is not true.

So, I would try using something else instead of `LocalDateTime`, maybe [check this approach](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10743).

**UPDATE**

Checking the Spring Framework's source code the [fully supported date types are these](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/auditing/AnnotationAuditingMetadata.java#L64) but for the `LocalDateTime` it uses [a read/write converter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters.java#L70).